# parse json using gson

Tags: json, parsing, gson

HI I have the following

```
 private List<Movie> movies;
...
 JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
 Gson gson = new Gson();                     
 SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
 movies = response.getResults();
```

the response.getResults() is throwing Null Pointer, but response it's not null can it be becuase I'm not handeling all the fields returned?

Movie class

```
@SerializedName("name") 
private String name;    
@SerializedName("sinopsis") 
private String sinopsis;
```

while the feed from a single movie looks like these (never mind the spanish)

```
{"@uri":"http://localhost:8080/Feeds/resources/peliculas/1/",
"elenco":"Director: Alejandro GonzÃ¡lez IÃ±arritu Reparto: Javier Bradem, Maricel   Alvarez,Martina GarcÃ­a, FÃ©lix Cubero, RubÃ©n Ochandiano Empresa Productora: Menageatroz, Focus Features, Mod Producciones, TelevisiÃ³n de Catalunya (TV3), TelevisiÃ³n EspaÃ±ola (TVE), Universal Pictures.",
"estreno":"83",
"fecha":"2010-03-05T16:31:02-02:00",
"idPelicula":"1",
"imagen1":"10_49.jpg",
"imagen2":"10_50.jpg",
"imagen3":"10_51.jpg",
"imagen4":"10_52.jpg",
"imagen5":"10_53.jpg",
"imagen6":"''",
"imagenTapa":"BiutifulTapa.jpg",
"name":"Biutiful",
"sinopsis":"Biutiful es la Ãºltima obra maestra de Alejandro GonzÃ¡lez IÃ±Ã¡rritu, el aclamado director de Amores Perros, 21 Gramos y Babel protagonizada por el premiado ganador del Oscar Javier Bardem. Padre abnegado. Amante atormentado. Hijo desamparado. Intermediario de la sombra. PrÃ³ximo a los desaparecidos. AtraÃ­do por los fantasmas. Sensible a los espÃ­ritus. Sobreviviente en el corazÃ³n de una Barcelona invisible. Sintiendo que la muerte le ronda, intenta encontrar la paz, proteger a sus hijos, salvarse a sÃ­ mismo.",
"trailer":"biutiful.flv"}
```

Thank you very much
Best regards.

Comment: im not sure is it related but you have field nanme while in gson string name

Comment: Justed edited typo while translating form span to engl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!!!!!!!

```
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            JsonElement rootElement = parser.parse(reader);
            SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(rootElement, SearchResponse.class);
            results = response.getResults();
```